# how to make an input element large

Tags: html

I have two input elements.

One is to put your email and the other is the email text.

How do I make the email input big enough to put a lot of text in it and be able to space down and stuff?

thanks

```
<form method="post" action="ttp.actions.emailAction.action">

                                    <h3>Email</h3>
                                <input name="email" id="email"/><br /><br />
                                <h3>Message</h3>
                                <input name="message" size="50" id="message"/>

                                <br />
                                <br />
                                <input type="submit" value="  Send  "/>

                                </form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `textarea` instead of `input`

```
<textarea name="email" id="email" rows="25" cols="80">Write stuff here...</textarea>
```

instead and you can set the size and other properties (scrolling etc...) using CSS.

```
textarea{
    width: 640px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [size attribute](http://www.tizag.com/htmlT/htmltextfields.php).

```
<input type="text" size="25" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Use textarea for large texts instead of input fields:

```
<textarea rows="5" cols="25"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/UBXBg/) of different methods to make input larger